# Exporting USDA NASS CDL 2005, 2007 using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export the USDA NASS CDL masks from 2003 to 2018. However, it seems that years 2005 and 2007 have two versions: 2005a, 2005b, 2007a, 2007b. Does anyone know why there's two, and how to remove or combine them otherwise? I tried checking the FAQ but it doesn't provide much information.

For reference,

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDA_NASS_CDL

I tried to remove 2005b and 2007b, but not sure how to filter them out using Google's api.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2002-12-31', '2018-12-31'))
              // This filter doesn't work.
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq("id", "USDA/NASS/CDL/2005b").not());

// Allows me to see number of elements in the query in the console.
print(dataset)

var cropLandcover = dataset.select('cropland');
Map.setCenter(-100.55, 40.71, 4);
Map.addLayer(cropLandcover, {}, 'Crop Landcover');
```

**Edit**:

Using the answer below, I found that 2005b adds information about Mississippi and 2007b adds information about California. There isn't any intersection, so it seems like you can just merge 2005a + 2005b and export that as one mask for 2005, and same with 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'b' images do not have the property "id". Look up the collection when printing to check which property they have, and you can use the filter on that:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2002-12-31', '2018-12-31'))
              // This filter doesn't work.
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", "2005b").not())
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", "2007b").not());
```